# How to set up icons in the ticket description on the Rally board?

Tags: rally

How to set up icons in the text on the Rally board? There is some way to provide this?

I.e on Jira is able to type `(/)` to provide a check icon. It's there similar in the Rally?

Comment: nope. there is no way to do it in rally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Adding icons to tickets in Rally board]

Is this what you mean (US96)? If so, the titles for cards can be (limited) html. This one is just an ampersand hash 129409 charactor in a html paragraph tag - which I can't add in here because this displays the icon not the text

I will display 🦁

If you don't want to change the title, you can add an arbtirary rich text field to your userstories and add that to the card and it will come up in the same way.